# How to map opencv to eigen with alignment support without allocate the memory?

Tags: c++, opencv, eigen

I use opencv to read big data from some data set(28*28 rows, 200000 cols) and want to map it to the Matrix of Eigen with alignment support without allocate another big buffer.

```
cv::Mat big_data(28*28, 200000, CV_64F);
//...read data and preprocess

EMatrix map_big_data;
//cv2Eigen will allocate a new, big buffer
cv::cv2Eigen(big_data, map_big_data);
```

Is it possible to map the matrix without allocate another big memory?It is okay to resize the cv::Mat, I want to avoid two big buffer exist at the same time(may throw bad_alloc)

```
cv::Mat big_data(28*28, 200000, CV_64F);
//read data and preprocess....

using EMatrix = Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic,
            Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>;
using EMap = Eigen::Map<EMatrix, Eigen::Aligned>;        

//resize the cv::Mat to meet the alignment requirement(16bytes aligned),is this possible?How could I get the align_cols?
big_data.resize(big_data.rows, align_cols);
//this may or may not crash
EMap map_big_data(reinterpret_cast<double*>(big_data.data),
big_data.rows,
big_data.cols);
```

Edit : Use Eigen::aligned_allocator to allocate align memory

```
Eigen::aligned_allocator<double> alloc;
int const Rows = 28*28;
int const Cols = 200000;
auto buffer = alloc.allocate(Rows*Cols);
cv::Mat big_data(Rows, Cols, CV_64F, buffer, Cols * sizeof(double));
//read data set and do some preprocess....

using EMatrix = Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic,
                Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>;
using EMap = Eigen::Map<EMatrix, Eigen::Aligned>; 

EMap map_big_data(reinterpret_cast<double*>(big_data.data),
    big_data.rows,
    big_data.cols);

//some jobs.....
alloc.deallocate(buffer, 0);
```

Is this ok?

Comment: What exactly are you alignment requirements?

Comment: @AviGinsburg I want the cv::Mat fit the alignment requirement of Eigen::Matrix(the doc said it is 16bytes), wondering it could be done with the help of Eigen::aligned_allocator or not

Comment: I don't really have time to go deep in it, but [this](http://computer-vision-talks.com/articles/mapping-eigen-to-opencv/) seems to be exacly what you want.

Comment: Did you try your most recent edit? Did it work?

Comment: @AviGinsburg It works, but not sure safe or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use the Eigen allocator directly at all? Use an Eigen::MatrixXd (or similar), and pass the pointer to the data to the cvMat constructor. Used that way, the cvMat "wraps" the data without copying it (same as the Eigen::Map).

```
int Rows = 28*28;
int Cols = 200000;
Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic,
            Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> eigenMat(Rows, Cols);

cv::Mat big_data(Rows, Cols, CV_64F, eigenMat.data(), Cols * sizeof(double));
//read data set and do some preprocess....
```

The only thing you shouldn't do is try and resize `big_data`, but rather `eigenMat` if necessary.

From the OpenCV [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a51615ebf17a64c968df0bf49b4de6a3a):

> **data**
>    Pointer to the user data. Matrix constructors that take data and step parameters do not allocate matrix data. Instead, they just initialize the matrix header that points to the specified data, which means that no data is copied. This operation is very efficient and can be used to process external data using OpenCV functions. The external data is not automatically deallocated, so you should take care of it.

This way there are no Maps, no trying to determine if there's extra padding, and no need to remember to deallocate. All this while still gaining all the advantages of an Eigen matrix.